# Member-function definition doesn't see "using declaration" in cpp file

Tags: c++11

There is a `round` function in a project in a separate namespace:

```
namespace CMMN
{
   inline long round (double x) { return long (x < 0. ? x-0.5 : x+0.5); }
}
```

Some class is declared in a *.h file and it's member functions are defined in a separate *.cpp file:

```
using CMMN::round;

long SOME_CLASS::MemberFunction()
{
   return round(sqrt(m_SomeValue));
}
```

The problem is that compiler generates an error:

```
error C2668: 'CMMN::round' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
          ...\commdef.h(222): could be 'long CMMN::round(double)'
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\math.h(1241): or       'long double round(long double) throw()'
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\math.h(1125): or       'float round(float) throw()'
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\math.h(516): or       'double round(double)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(double)'
```

- I wonder why ussing declaration in the begining of the cpp file does
  not affect memeber function definitions below?
- Is there a way to make
  using declaration be seen inside member function definition? *Adding using declaration for each function definition inside is a decision, but it is almost equivalent to full-qualified `round` calls.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using CMMN::round` within a namespace only makes that symbol visible within said namespace; it does *not* affect binding preference.

You appear to have also included `<cmath>` or `<math.h>` somewhere, which also declare overloads of `round`.

You will have to either place using declarations within function definitions, or fully qualify their names where they are used.

Answer (score 1):

It does affect it. The compiler is telling you that there are 4 candidate functions that it could call, and it doesn't know which one to call. One of those candidates is CMMN::round, which shows that the using declaration is being recognized.

You have to disambiguate which `round()` you intend for it to call.

Comment: What's the difference then with using declaration inside definition? There should be 4 candidates as well, but it compiles without errors...

Comment: And one more thing, seems CMMN is publicated to global scope somewhere in dependecies - without **using declaration** behavior is the same as described in the first post.

Comment: Ah, got it at last... The fact, that the situation didn't change after adding **using declaration**, confused me. Marked _defube_'s answer as solution, but thank you too.